# Call to undefined method Illuminate\Http\Request::angel.jpg()

Tags: php, laravel

### I have a form, I have troubles in Upload an Image :(

I am trying to upload some image and I don't know what I am doing bad :(

```
 {{ Form::open (['route' => 'titulos.store', 'class'=> 'form', 'files'=> 'true']) }}

    {{ Form::label('title', "Titulo:", ['class' => 'col-sm-2 control-label']) }}

    {{ Form::text('title') }}
        {{ $errors->first('title') }}
            
    <div class="form-group">          
      {{ Form::label('date', "Fecha:", ['class' => 'col-sm-2 control-label']) }}
      <input type="date" name="date" >              
    </div>

    {{ Form::label('description', "Description:", ['class' => 'col-sm-2 control-label']) }}
        {{ Form::textarea('description') }}
        {{ $errors->first('description') }}
    
    <div class="form-group">
        {{ Form::file('image') }}
    </div>

        {{ Form::label('category_id', 'Category:', ['class' => 'col-sm-2 control-label']) }}
            <div class="col-sm-10">
             {{ Form::select('category_id', array('1' => 'TBLeaks', '2' => 'Quejas', '3' => 'Denuncias', '4' => 'Ideas'), null, array('class' => 'form-control')) }}
            </div>

        <div class="row">       
            <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
        {{ Form::submit('Submit', ['class' => "btn btn-primary"]) }}
            </div>
        </div>
            

        <div class="row">       
            <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
                <a class="btn btn-success" href="{{ URL::to('admin') }}">Back to Admin</a>
            </div>          
        </div>  
        {{ Form::close() }}
    </div>


@if(Session::has('message'))
    <div class="alert alert-{{ Session::get('class') }}">{{ Session::get('message')}}</div>
@endif
```

@stop

### In my store function I have:

class TitulosController extends BaseController {

public function store(){

```
    $rules = array(
        'title'         => 'required',
        'description'   => 'required',           
        'category_id'   => 'required'
    );
    $validator = Validator::make(Input::all(), $rules);

    // proceso de valicion
    if ($validator->fails()) {
        return Redirect::to('titulos/create')
            ->withErrors($validator)
            ->withInput()->withErrors($validator);
    } else {


    //store
    $image = Input::file('image');
    $filename = $image->getClientOriginalName();
    
    if(Input::hasFile('image')){
        Input::file('image')->move(public_path().'/assets/img/', $filename);
    }
    
    $titulo = new Titulo();
    $titulo->id             = Input::get('id');
    $titulo->title          = Input::get('title');    
    $titulo->description    = Input::get('description');
    $titulo->date           = Input::get('date');    
    $titulo->image          = Input::$filename('image');
    $titulo->category_id    = Input::get('category_id');
    
    $titulo->save();

    return Redirect::to('titulos');        
}
```

### I have this model for the Titulo table:

class Titulo extends Eloquent {

```
use SoftDeletingTrait; // for soft delete

protected $dates = ['deleted_at']; // for soft delete   

protected $table = 'titulos';

protected $primaryKey = 'id';

protected $fillable = array('image');

public $timestamps = true;

public function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
    
}

public function category(){
    return $this->belongsTo('Category');
}
```

}

### I have this for Image model:

class Image extends Eloquent {

```
public $timestamps = false;
protected $fillable = array('image');
```

}

Comment: Did you chmod permission folder assets/img/ ?

Comment: Yes, I was trying to upolad from public/assets/img/angel.jpg. Thank you :) mydo47

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At this line where your store to public path should be no problem

```
if(Input::hasFile('image')){
    Input::file('image')->move(public_path().'/assets/img/', $filename);
}
```

Only your save Tutilo object looks not good. I think you have mistakenly add `$` on `Input::filename` at this line. which will call the image

```
$titulo->image = Input::$filename('image');
```

change your code to this

```
$titulo = new Titulo();
$titulo->id             = Input::get('id');
$titulo->title          = Input::get('title');    
$titulo->description    = Input::get('description');
$titulo->date           = Input::get('date');    
$titulo->image          = $filename; // I change this line. assuming you want to store the file name
$titulo->category_id    = Input::get('category_id');
```

Comment: I add the $ to the input, the error changed to:  **Function name must be a string** in:  <br/>  `$titulo->image = Input::$file('image');` I am new in this Laravel world, thanks in advance @cod3rite :D – Chiki 6 mins ago

Comment: What i mean is, remove that $ so it become `Input::file`

Comment: Thank you very much  **cod3rite** I am doing something bad :( , my store function is:  <br>

Comment: Please see this link, I upload the complete Store Function  `"http://www.hiii.com/img"`

Comment: OMG!!!! you are a Genie!!!!! Thank you very much!!! you haven't idea how I was suffering with this. Thanks again from New Zealand xoxoxoxo :D